# How does Mathematica calculate its AdjacencyMatrix[ ] and VertexDegree[ ]

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I define a graph:

```
g = Graph[{1 \[UndirectedEdge] 3, 2 \[UndirectedEdge] 4, 
3 \[UndirectedEdge] 4, 3 \[UndirectedEdge] 5, 
4 \[UndirectedEdge] 5, 5 \[UndirectedEdge] 6}, 
VertexLabels -> "Name"]
```

The output looks correct in how the vertices are connected, but the `AdjacencyMatrix[g]` and `VertexDegree[g]` put the vertices out of order with my labels.

Why is that, and what is the order *Mathematica* uses?

Comment: Vertex ordering is completely unrelated to the names of the vertices.  Vertices can be any expression, not just numbers.  Never assume that numerical vertices are ordered from smallest to greatest.  Use `VertexIndex` and `VertexList` to relate the index of a vertex to the vertex itself.  In practice, Mathematica puts the vertices in the order you first specify them (as they appear in the edge list in your example), but never count on this as there's no guarantee and I won't be surprised if future versions change this.

Comment: I removed the [tag:implementation-details] tag because the question is more about *what the function returns* than about *how the function works internally*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[AdjacencyMatrix >> Details](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/AdjacencyMatrix.html):

[image]

[VertexList >> Details](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/VertexList.html):

[image]

So, unless you provide a vertex list as the first argument of `Graph`, `VertexList[g]` is populated with vertices in the order they appear in the edge list, i.e., `{1, 3, 2, 4, 5, 6}`. Using `Range[6]` as the first argument in `Graph`:

```
g1 = Graph[Range[6], {1 \[UndirectedEdge] 3, 2 \[UndirectedEdge] 4, 
   3 \[UndirectedEdge] 4, 3 \[UndirectedEdge] 5, 
   4 \[UndirectedEdge] 5, 5 \[UndirectedEdge] 6}, 
  VertexLabels -> "Name", ImagePadding -> 10]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

versus

```
g2 = Graph[{1 \[UndirectedEdge] 3, 2 \[UndirectedEdge] 4, 
   3 \[UndirectedEdge] 4, 3 \[UndirectedEdge] 5, 
   4 \[UndirectedEdge] 5, 5 \[UndirectedEdge] 6}, 
  VertexLabels -> "Name", ImagePadding -> 10]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Their `VertexList`s and `VertexDegree`s:

```
Column[Labeled[TableForm[{VertexList@#, VertexDegree@#}, 
     TableHeadings -> {{"VertexList", "VertexDegree"}, None}], #2, 
    Top] & @@@ {{g1, "g1"}, {g2, "g2"}}, Spacings -> 2]
```

[image]

and `AdjacencyMatrix`s:

```
Row[Labeled[TableForm[Normal@AdjacencyMatrix@#, 
            TableHeadings -> {VertexList@#, VertexList@#}], 
      #2, Top] & @@@ {{g1, "g1"}, {g2, "g2"}}, Spacer[15]]
```

[image]